# Blueprint properties placeholder

Tags: properties, apache-karaf, blueprint

Here is my blueprint:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd                            http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint https://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
    <bean class="ph.edu.dlsu.esb.CogMockProcessor" id="CogMockProcessor"/>
    
    <cm:property-placeholder id="cogmock.properties"
        persistent-id="custom.properties" update-strategy="reload">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="cogmock.host" value="//localhost"/>
            <cm:property name="cogmock.port" value="8989"/>
            <cm:property name="cogmock.path"
                value="/external/grade/updatestudentgrade"/>
            <cm:property name="cogmock.protocol" value="http"/>
            <cm:property name="cogmock.OpenId.Token"
                value="9GC1hnEeNIWVbehmxxjUwkj1Wcx2Y-P7SgOUZvVUzkM"/>

        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>
    
    <camelContext id="_mockcontext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="_route1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="restlet:http://localhost:{{cogmock.port}}/external/grade/updatestudentgrade?restletMethod=POST">
                <description>Mock the Camu Change of Grade API</description>
            </from>
            <process id="_process1" ref="CogMockProcessor"/>
            <log id="_log1" message="I'm here"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

Here is my fuse-karaf/etc/custom.properties

```
#
# You can place any customized configuration here.
#
cogmock.protocol=http
cogmock.host=//localhost
cogmock.port=8989
cogmock.path=/external/grade/updatestudentgrade
cogmock.OpenId.Token=9GC1hnEeNIWVbehmxxjUwkj1Wcx2Y-P7SgOUZvVUzkM
```

It Builds successfully but when I bundle:install -s ... I get:

```
Unable to start container for blueprint bundle CogMock/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
```

If I take out the {{cogmock.port}} everything works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Tried cogmock.cfg in /etc and changed persistentId=cogmock to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

`update-strategy="reload"` can be added to your blueprint XML only when you use `xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"` or later. It doesn't work with `xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"`.

And to be clear `persistent-id` attribute means PID, which (when using etc/ configuration) is created from files with `*.cfg` extension. So if you have `persistent-id="cogmock"`, you need `$FUSE_HOME/etc/cogmock.cfg` file with your properties.

Comment: Yes that was all it took.  v1.1.0 vs v1.0.0! Thanks, I had already set cogmock.cfg in /etc and matching persistent-id="cogmock"  Thank you.